# Unzipped xml text contents mangled

Tags: java, zip, jetty, unzip

I have a problem unziping xml signed and it's altered.

Client sent this XML:

```
    <DatoAdicional>
        <Codigo>03</Codigo>
        <Valor>: REGULARIZACI�N DEL VALOR FACTURADO*: DEBE SER:   30.29*: VALOR FACTURADO:  30.00*</Valor>
    </DatoAdicional>
```

But when unziping we get(it's altered):

```
<DatoAdicional>
    <Codigo>03</Codigo>
    <Valor>: REGULARIZACI???N DEL VALOR FACTURADO*: DEBE SER:   30.29*: VALOR FACTURADO:  30.00*</Valor>
</DatoAdicional>
```

The problem is that when it unziped inside server jetty because when that zip is unziped with a client java it is unziped sucessfully. My code java is:

```
public static List<ZipContent> getXml(DataHandler file) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zis = null;
    List<ZipContent> zipContents = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        zis = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());
        for (ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry(); ze != null; ze = zis.getNextEntry()) {
            if (!ze.isDirectory()) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1 << 11];
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    byteArrayOs.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                ZipContent zc = new ZipContent();
                zc.setFileName(ze.getName());
                zc.setXml(new String(byteArrayOs.toByteArray()));
                zipContents.add(zc);
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
        }
        zis.close();
        return zipContents;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Hepl me please.

Comment: Not sure how/why jetty fits into this question.  Nothing in your example code uses anything in the servlet spec or jetty.

Comment: Because that method unzip well when is call from another client then I think it could be because of Jetty

Answer (score 1):

`new String(byteArrayOs.toByteArray())` creates a String out of a byte array using the system's default encoding. On Windows systems this is most likely e.g. cp1252 (on german systems, yours might vary). I don't know the class ZipContent but you might either set the bytes instead of converting it to text or use the correct charset by using e.g. `new String(byteArrayOs.toByteArray(), "utf8")`

Comment: Mi application is on centos server. I did that change but I still have the similar error, now we get:  <DatoAdicional>
      <Codigo>03</Codigo>
      <Valor>: REGULARIZACI?N DEL VALOR FACTURADO*: DEBE SER:   30.29*: VALOR FACTURADO:  30.00*</Valor>
     </DatoAdicional>

Comment: I was so sick with that problem that I changed Jetty for another new(the same version), and now everything it's OK. Still I don't know why I had that problem.